# How to put submit_tag button in one line with other buttons in bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a snippet of Rails code showing 4 buttons. The problem is that button `CSV` is not in the same line as other 3 buttons and is on a 2nd line.

```
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
           <%= link_to t('Back'), SUBURI + "/authentify/view_handler?index=0", :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action']  %>
           <%= link_to t('Search'), SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{search_payment_requests_path}", :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] if has_action_right?('search', params[:controller]) %>
           <%= link_to t('Stats'), SUBURI + "/view_handler?index=1&url=#{stats_payment_requests_path}", :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] if has_action_right?('stats', params[:controller]) %>
           <%= form_tag export_file_payment_requests_path(format: 'csv'), method: :patch do %>
              <% record_ids = models.page(params[:page]).per_page(10000).pluck('id') %>
              <%= submit_tag 'CSV', :name => "save[#{record_ids}]" %>
           <% end %>
   </div>
```

Here is how the button look like:

[image]

Here is the html source code:
[image]

The problem is that the `CSV` button is a submit button on a `form` element:

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" href="/authentify/view_handler?index=0">
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" href="/authentify/view_handler?index=1&url=/pr/payment_requests/search">
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" href="/authentify/view_handler?index=1&url=/pr/payment_requests/stats">
    </a>
    </div>
    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pr/payment_requests/export_file.csv">
    <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
    <input type="hidden" value="patch" name="_method">
    <input type="hidden" value="N4/rNWV7FVB+lq1ul3u08tx79mhlaH1GE9GiCrpP0+6ROHHoySxg6cQhnHbbygGf6Fng==" name="authenticity_token">
    <input class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" type="submit" value="CSV" name="save[[1244, 1243, 1242, 1241, 1240, 1239, 1238, 1237, 1236, 1235, 1234, 1233, 1112, 1100, 1054, 1018]]">
    </form>
    </div>
```

We tried `<div class="form-group">` with no avail. Is there a way to put `submit_tag` button in the same line with other 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.btn-toolbar form {
  padding: 0;
  top: -1px;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 60px; text-align: center;">

  <div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" href="/authentify/view_handler?index=0">Link 1
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" href="/authentify/view_handler?index=1&url=/pr/payment_requests/search">Link 2
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" href="/authentify/view_handler?index=1&url=/pr/payment_requests/stats"> Link 3
    </a>

    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pr/payment_requests/export_file.csv">
      <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
      <input type="hidden" value="patch" name="_method">
      <input type="hidden" value="N4/rNWV7FVB+lq1ul3u08tx79mhlaH1GE9GiCrpP0+6ROHHoySxg6cQhnHbbygGf6Fng==" name="authenticity_token">
      <input class="btn btn-md btn-hover btn-primary" type="submit" value="CSV" name="save[[1244, 1243, 1242, 1241, 1240, 1239, 1238, 1237, 1236, 1235, 1234, 1233, 1112, 1100, 1054, 1018]]">
    </form>
  </div>
```

---

I updated the response. You need to place the form inside the toolbar and add the CSS I provided to your CSS.

Comment: Where does the 4th button `CSV` go? `btn-toolbar` and `btn-group` behave the same here. We have no problem lining up the first 3 buttons.

Comment: Can you post the resulting html? I can't inspect a picture, can I?

Comment: The css was added to `application.css.scss` and was loaded with the page. However the `CSV` button is still on 2nd line.

Comment: That means you haven't given me a [mcve]. Did you double check the markup? In your initial code, you were closing the toolbar before starting the form. Could that be it?

Comment: Where did you see the toolbar div closed before form? In both examples the div toolbar includes the <form> tag. Even with the Rails code, the div toolbar covers the form tag.

Comment: Look closelly before the opening of the form. You are closing the `</div>`. You need to place the form inside the toolbar. If you can't do it via Ruby, do it in the page, using javascript, after page load. I'll update with a script that does this for you in a few mins.

Comment: It works now. The problem may be the app was not loaded properly. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of putting CSV on the left as first one, how to make it to the right as last button? Tried `float: right;` and it goes all the way to the right of the page.

Comment: You should ad a custom `class` to your `.md-toolbar` element and give it a `max-width` in `px` or `%` via CSS